# How to limit a subprocess's ability to set its children's CPU affinity?

Tags: linux, affinity

Suppose there is a root process (R) that can create a subprocess (S). S can create its own subprocesses (s1, s2, ...). R can set the CPU affinity of S during S's creation. However, I don't want S to modify its CPU affinity or break the CPU affinity when creating its own subprocesses.

For example, R may set S to use CPU 1-10 to run itself. S may modify it, but it cannot use CPU cores that greater than 10. And when S create s1, s2..., it cannot assign CPU cores other than 1-10 to them.

I can control R's logic but I cannot control the logic of S, s1, s2... Are there anyway to force S and its subprocesses to use specific CPU cores when R creating S?

Add more info as Charles Duffy said "there are lots of different ways to do this, and there's not enough details present in the question to be able to disqualify any of them."

- The OS is Ubuntu 18.04 / 20.04
- You can consider R as a bash script and S should be created inside it.

With the above info, are there any demo that can shows a way to do that?

Comment: You can always drop permissions or change the mount table or enable syscall filtering before the final exec.

Comment: ...and if you use SELinux or a similar layer, then you have even more fine-grained control.

Comment: ...honestly, because you haven't done your tool selection yet, I'm not sure this is narrow enough to be a sound question; there are _lots_ of different ways to do this (where the selection in part will depend on things like what level of permissions R runs with, what kernel version/distro/etc you run, what languages your development staff are comfortable with, etc etc etc), and there's not enough details present in the question to be able to disqualify any of them.

Comment: Look into [LSMs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.16/admin-guide/LSM/index.html) for various mechanisms to provide extra access-control rules on top of the stock kernel -- many if not all of those can have rules to prevent some processes but not others from writing certain files / invoking certain syscalls. Depending on what other things S needs to be able to do, you may also be able to use [seccomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) or [seccomp bpf](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/userspace-api/seccomp_filter.html) or similar.

Comment: Since you've clarified that R is a shell script, that rules out _directly_ invoking seccomp &c -- but tell firejail or any other frontend for seccomp to mask out `sched_setaffinity` while starting S, and there you are.